# How to register a dependency when creating laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package

I would like to know how to register a dependency when creating laravel package.

In my package `composer.json` I have :

```
{
    "name": "facilinfo/gallery",
    "description": "Photo galleries management package for laravel",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": ["laravel"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "facilinfo",
            "email": "contact@facil-info.net"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Facilinfo\\Gallery\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

And when I do

```
$form = new Form();
```

I have a `Class not found` error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to autoload your own files or is the Form you're trying to use some third party lib?

Comment: I am trying to use the Collective Form in a view of my package.

Comment: It's probably a namespace issue.  Try `$form = new \Form();`

Comment: Finally, I found the soultion myself. I had tout add this to my package service provider: `code` $this->app->register(\Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class);

        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('Form', '\Collective\Html\FormFacade');`code` and to add  "laravelcollective/html": " 5.2.*" in the laravel installation where I'm developping my package and install in. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the soultion myself. I had tout add this to my package service provider register function:

```
 $this->app->register(\Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class);
    $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
    $loader->alias('Form', '\Collective\Html\FormFacade');
```

and to add  "laravelcollective/html": " 5.2.*" in the laravel installation where I'm developping my package and install in. It works now.